# How to show the compile error's details on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I just pulled the code from a fellow developer and get the following error :

[image]

I remember Android studio used to be more verbose about the type of problem, but the latest version just give me that generic error.

How can I get more details about this compiling error ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Type below command in the terminal of Android Studio

`./gradlew build --stacktrace`

Check stack trace you will find the error

Comment: This is the way. Side note, under windows the command is gradlew build --stacktrace

Answer (score 8):

There is a toggle view button into the Build view to see the details.

[image]  [image]