# How can I view compiler error details in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Got this when trying to build my project:
[image]

How can I get more details on this error? Double clicking the lines doesn't work. A toggle view button as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809306/how-to-show-the-compile-errors-details-on-android-studio) isn't available in my Android Studio version (latest stable -> Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2).

Comment: Doesn't the log file contain more details?

Comment: which log file?

Comment: As you can see the second line has "See log for more details". `Toolbar > Help Menu > Show log in Explorer`

Comment: You might find some more error information in the Logcat view in the bottom toolbar. Or View > Tool Window > Logcat